# git bash on windows: interactive mode doesn't work

Tags: windows, git, mingw

Well, the problem is any command involving manipulations with patches refuses to work in the following manner:

```
<stdin>:16: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:17: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:18: trailing whitespace.    
<stdin>:19: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:20: trailing whitespace.
warning: recount: unexpected line:   
fatal: corrupt patch at line 101
```

(As a result?) Interactive mode doesn't work.
Tried to tweak `core.whitespace` with no success.

Please help me to resolve this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

This message usually comes from the `pre-commit` hook when its checking for non-ascii content.

The sample pre-commit hook may be doing a check for trailing whitespace.
To disable it, look in `.git/hooks` and make sure the files there are not executable.

---

`###git-stripspace`

Read
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stripspace.html